# iOS App Version Number in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app in the App Store at version 1.1.6. I then submitted a new version/update with a version number of 1.1.7. The update was approved and now if you download the app you get all the changes that were submitted in 1.1.7 when you download the app.

However, the App Store still shows the version as 1.1.6, and when you install the app it shows as 1.1.6 on the device.

What happened to the 1.1.7 version number? I have read through the iTunes guide for [new versions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1) and I think I got everything right. Can anyone shed light on how to get the version number to update when a new version is submitted?

I have another update (1.2.0) but don't want to submit it until I understand how to get the version number to change. Thanks.

EDIT: Some additional info. Version 1.1.6 and 1.1.7 were essentially released at the same time. 1.1.6 was "Ready for Sale" but had not been released to the app store. Once 1.1.7 was approved, we released them at the same time. Not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: What version number does iTunes Connect show? And can you confirm that you set it as version 1.1.7 in Xcode before you submitted it?

Comment: @Gavin - Right now iTunes shows 1.1.6. We did not tag the 1.1.7 build in svn before we started on new changes so I don't have a way to go back and confirm that the Info.plist actually had 1.1.7. It was my understanding that iTunes wouldn't let you submit a new version with the same number but I may be wrong?

Comment: I would recommend contacting Apple and asking them about it. Also, do you print out the version anywhere in the app itself? Sometimes on an about screen or login screen, apps tend to display the version number. If you have that, and it displays 1.1.6, my guess would be you somehow submitted a new version that didn't increment the version number.

Comment: You should read the following question and its answer by the same user, since it points to Apple server error, which is quite probably your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610034/ios-7-users-unable-to-install-new-version/19610385

Comment: Seeing your edit, are you sure that the version available is your 1.1.7 version?

Comment: @Gavin - We are not printing out the version in the app anywhere right now but something we have considered. We noticed it when looking at our Google Analytics. We retrieve the version number from the app and send that in to GA. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Gavin - Yes. We made some changes to results filtering and included some bug fixes that are there when you download from the app store. Those changes were in 1.1.7.

Comment: @Injuanj - Thanks for the link. Good information. Our issue seems to be just the opposite. The App Store shows 1.1.6, but also shows the "Whats New" section for what was included in 1.1.7. And when you download you definitely get the latest.