# Same app after an update in iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-store

We requested an expedited review for an update of our app that fixed a critical bug. The expedited review was granted and now our version 1.1 is up instead of our version 1.0. But the app is the same.

The changes we made to the app are not in the new version. We have an ad hoc version of the same binary and in the ad hoc version the changes are there. I dont know if somebody has had the same issue and if there was a way to fix it. This is our first expedited review and already contacted iTunes developer support but we are still waiting for their response.

Maybe now it takes time to propagate the servers with the new app or somehow the metadata for version 1.1 was passed to the appstore with the binary for 1.0. This is the first time we ever had problems after an update.

Comment: You just had a notification it was approved? Did you check the version number after downloading the new version?

Comment: The new app can take up to 24 hours to propagate, but it should propagate synchronously with the meta information.

Comment: Yes the update is ready for sale since two days ago and on the store is marked as version 1.1. https://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/screencast/id792222937?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be one of two options:
- The servers (Apple's servers) have not still propagated the correct version.
- The servers have inconsistent information, so they won't propagate the current version till you contact Apple. This happened to a dev some months ago and here is his answer: [iOS 7 users unable to install new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610034/ios-7-users-unable-to-install-new-version/19610385)

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what is happening. Thanks for the link, I spent hours looking for some explanation or past experiences with this issue on SO and other forums.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a common problem at the moment. See

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70511

My app is 'Ready for sale' for almost 48 hours now, but the AppStore still shows the previous version.